# Zend: Calling an action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to get my head around the Zend Framework.

I've created a custom route

```
resources.router.routes.helloworld.route = /helloworld
resources.router.routes.helloworld.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.helloworld.defaults.controller = helloworld
resources.router.routes.helloworld.defaults.action = display
```

In my hellowrold controller class I have changed the `indexAction()` name to `displayAction()`.

when I try to load the page in a browser I get the following error message:
'script'xxx/display.phtml' not found in path(C:/:blah blah blah)'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Zend Framework controller actions use the ViewRenderer Controller helper. This helper reads a .phtml file related to the action as the View Script of the related action.

The controller accesses models and in the end passes the result data to view scripts, so view scripts could present the data. This is the "V" in the "MVC" abbreviation.

For your case, you have specified that your default action is named "display" instead of "index".

But I think you have forgotten to create a view script file for this action.
By default the view scripts are located in the **APPLICATION_PATH/application/views/scripts** directory, with these assumptions:

1. **APPLICATION_PATH** is where your application structure and public directory reside in, (for example /var/www/ on Debain Linux or C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache\htdocs on Windows).
2. You are keeping the source code of your application (including your models, controllers, modules, etc.) in the directory called **application**
3. If you are having modules in your application and for example your modules are defined in application/modules; then the **view/scripts** directory is located in each module directory instead of the root of the application structure.

In the above directory, each controller should have a related subdirectory, and each action have a view script file in .phtml extension.

You should create a directory called "helloworld" in there, and then create a file named "display.phtml" in that directory, so the ViewRendere controller helper class could load it and use it as the view of this action.

If you do not want to have a view script, you should prevent the ViewRendere helper from searching for a view script file. to do so, add this code to your action in the controller code:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
```

This code tells the view renderer action helper not to search for a view script file.

Please not that all the above are mentioned for a default configured Zend Framework application, but could be changed by configuring your application, resources and helper objects.

Comment: Thanks, a very clear and detailed explanation. I didn't get that actions are by default tied to a view. I evidently have a lot to learn.